# How to make ⌫ symbol backward-compatible in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, backwards-compatibility

The backspace symbol '⌫' gets displayed on my device running the Android API version 28 but not on my emulator running the API version 15. I am using the following code. Please help

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/backspace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:text="\u232b"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
```

Comment: You can try using an Image for the icon and then use `ImageButton` to display it same on all API versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that old android versions doesn't have the font that support this symbol so you have to use a supported **font-family** for this button you can check supported ones [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/232b/fontsupport.htm)
and use the downloaded font you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) for how to do that don't forget [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml#using-support-lib) section for old apis but here min **api-level** are **16**

and use it like

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/backspace"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:text="\u232b"
    android:fontFamily="@font/myfont" //your downloaded font family name
    android:textSize="35sp"
/>
```

if you need to support api 15 you can use

```
val typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.myfont)
button.typeface = typeface
```