# Remove Extra Space between Views

Tags: java, android, xml, image, button

[image]

I'm building a simple calculator app and i cannot get ride of extra grey lines next to an ImageButton

Button Code

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button_clear"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:text="AC"
  android:textColor="@color/indigo"
  android:textSize="18sp" />
```

ImageButton Code

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button_back"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/backspace"
  android:background="@color/white"/>
```

As you can see, the buttons are perfect but the ImageButton have grey lines next to them.
I tried settings the Parent background to 'White' and setting the ImageButton background to '@null' too
I tried an Imageview and the Problem still exists
i tried setting the image as background to the button and it still exists
i even tried setting negative margin towards left and right and the problem still exists

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Can you share the full xml of this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your ImageButtons

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion: Use a button to display the ⌫ symbol. For information on how to get the desired results visit: [How to make ⌫ symbol backward-compatible in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357337/how-to-make-symbol-backward-compatible-in-android-studio)